# Bootstrap modal backend to frontend view

Tags: php, mysql, web-services, web

I am trying to send the data to the backend on a new front-end, the backend is working to display the bootstrap modal except the front end display is previewing this error. It is successfully adding but without retrieving the validation set from the js file.

```
Uncaught TypeError: $(...).DataTable is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (customers.js:8)
```

from

```
 manageCustomerTable = $("#manageCustomerTable").DataTable({
        'ajax': 'php_action/fetchCustomers.php',
        'order': []     
    });
```

I am a newbie to programming, all I want to do is sign-up the customer to send the details to the backend successfully from the new front-end view for the customer.

```
<?php 
require_once 'php_action/db_connect.php'; 



?>
<?php require_once 'php_action/core.php'; ?>



<?php require_once 'includes/header.php'; ?>


<table class="table" id="manageCustomerTable">

</table>

    <form class="form-horizontal" id="submitCustomerForm" action="php_action/createCustomers.php" method="POST">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title"><i class="fa fa-plus"></i> Add Beautician</h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body">

                <div id="add-customer-messages"></div>



    <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="c_Title" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Title: </label>
                    <label class="col-sm-1 control-label">: </label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" id="c_Title" placeholder="Title Name" name="c_Title" autocomplete="off">
                        </div>
                </div> <!-- /form-group-->  









              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="createCustomerBtn" data-loading-text="Loading..." autocomplete="off">Save Changes</button>
              </div>
              <!-- /modal-footer -->
            </form>
             <!-- /.form -->




    <script src="custom/js/customers.js"></script>
```

Comment: it looks like you didnt include datatable.js in html. paste entire page here

Comment: done already added, help is appreciated